# executable "running" but not working

Tags: 20.04, executable

I'm trying to run an executable for some time and can't get it to work. I already gave the chmod +x permissions, but the file seems to run but do not work as it should.

This is the ls -l results:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gabriel gabriel   620 jan 22  2020 plasys.inp
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gabriel gabriel 29536 jan 22  2020 Resonalyzerv2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gabriel gabriel 28792 jan 22  2020 Superatlasv2
```

I need to use both the Resonalyzer and the Superatlas, but when i execute with './file' they just "run" and get me back to the terminal when they should ask me to input some values and then return me results. Here it is the terminal when i try to execute them:

```
(base) gabriel@brainiac:~/IC/tabare/linux$ ./Resonalyzerv2 
(base) gabriel@brainiac:~/IC/tabare/linux$
```

and:

```
(base) gabriel@brainiac:~/IC/tabare/linux$ ./Superatlasv2 
(base) gabriel@brainiac:~/IC/tabare/linux$
```

My professor used the same files as me and did the same process and it worked for him. I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and he 16.04

EDIT

ldd for Resonalyzer results in:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffec50af000)
    libf2c.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libf2c.so.2 (0x00007f28efb7a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f28efa2b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f28ef839000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f28efdb3000)
```

for Superatlas:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc0b1e9000)
   libf2c.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libf2c.so.2 (0x00007feff818f000)
   libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007feff8040000)
   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007feff7e4e000)
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007feff83c8000)
```

file command for Resonalyzer:

```
Resonalyzerv2: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=e95bde4f8cc35d6884e7b7a996972c8670d88045, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

for Superatlas:

```
Superatlasv2: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0ff6fce0ffe2c4da50e2a34a765ad6d916ef823d, not stripped
```

Comment: You may be missing a shareable library, check with `ldd Resonalyzerv2` and `ldd Superatlasv2`. Also `file Resonalyzerv2 Superatlasv2`.

Comment: Maybe your professor's runtime environment differs from yours. Can you get your professor to run `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` and compare it with your execution of same.

Comment: @waltinator when i run ldd i get:


`linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe939f1000)
 libf2c.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libf2c.so.2 (0x00007f3175126000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3174fd7000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3174de5000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f317535f000)`

how can i know if one of them it's missing?

EDIT: i can't figure it out how to organize the code

Comment: the file command result was: `Resonalyzerv2: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=7e45ed96948306c247dfed7d78edb9fe0cf4b61b, not stripped` and `Superatlasv2: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0ff6fce0ffe2c4da50e2a34a765ad6d916ef823d, not stripped`

Comment: The programs appear to have been compiled using fort77 (hence the dependence on libf2c.so) - I wonder if it is this issue: [fort77: no output to stdout or stderr](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fort77/+bug/1821845)

Comment: my machine is also amd64... Tried looking for similar questions over the internet and it seems like still there is no fixing for that, right?

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: ... assuming you have the source code from the zipfile [here](http://www.fisica.edu.uy/~gallardo/atlas/2bmmr2020.html) I'd suggest recompiling it using gfortran ex. `mv Resonalyzerv2 Resonalyzerv2.old; gfortran -std=legacy -O3 -o Resonalyzerv2 ../source/Resonalyzerv2.f`

Comment: Recompiling using gfortran worked! Thank you so much, now i can continue my research. I'll add the extra information on the post as well in case another person finds the same problem. Thank a lot for the support guys

Comment: @alakazam thanks for the confirmation - I have added an answer below summarizing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to run `./Resonalyzerv2` from the author's provided zip archive [here](http://www.fisica.edu.uy/%7Egallardo/atlas/2bmmr2020.html) on my 18.04 system, and can confirm that it exits immediately with status 0.

Based on your `ldd` output, we can guess that the program was compiled using `fort77` - which uses `f2c` under the hood to convert legacy Fortran code to C.

There is a [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fort77/+bug/1821845) in the Ubuntu `fort77` package that matches the symptoms you describe. Running a version recompiled using fort77 with debugging (`f77 -g`) shows that it exits with

```
[Inferior 1 (process 27235) exited normally]
```

before even attempting to write the program's banner. My `strace`-fu is weak, but `strace ./Resonalyzerv2` does not appear to be much more informative.

I don't know if any progress has been made in resolving the bug, or if it affects later Ubuntu versions, but since the zip archive includes Fortran source code of the two programs you can try compiling them yourself using `gfortran` instead of `fort77`.

First, install the `gfortran` package if you have not already done so. Then either:

1. compile using `gfortran` directly, perhaps using the `legacy` code standard

   ```
    gfortran -std=legacy -o Resonalyzerv2 ../source/Resonalyzerv2.f
   ```

or

2. compile using the gfortran-provided version of `f77`

   ```
    f77 -o Resonalyzerv2 ../source/Resonalyzerv2.f
   ```

If you have installed `ifort` as well as `gfortran`, then you will need to use `update-alternatives` to confirm which package is providing `f77` and adjust if necessary.